# Server Client preferences between languages

Tags: java, c++, networking, client-server, tcp

When TCP/IP networking between different languages, is there an advantage to using a server on one language compared to another? I'm communicating between C++ and Java, and wondering if having a server on a specific language will improve it's overall efficiency, or is the client server relationship agnostic in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Personally I'd do them *both* in Java unless I had some clear requirements for performance considerations, and I *hate* Java. But their networking library is such cake to use for simple tasks like this its really hard to argue against it.

Comment: I fail to see how can you have a problem with efficiency, before you have the program. First write the code, then optimize as necessary.

Comment: We need to use both C++ and java, i am just wondering what would be easier to use.

Comment: Sending data over a network is I/O-bound, not CPU bound. The choice of language therefore isn't likely to make any difference to efficiency of execution. If efficiency of development is included in your concerns, which it should be, Java wins hands down, at both ends. I don't understand why you 'need to use both C++ and Java', unless this is homework.

Comment: This is for my robotics club, and we're using the kinect this year. My club has limited knowledge when it comes to the kinect, so that's where i come in(C++). The other programmer knows only java, so we're going to send strings to each other(kinect and robot) to represent depth values. The kinect will be mounted on the robot and act as its eye, measuring the distance from all object in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use whatever you find easier to use. We can't tell you which one that is.

If you still have no idea, I would suggest Java as its easier for beginners and harder to shoot yourself with ;)

I wouldn't worry about performance until you have specific, measurable requirements have measured how your application performs.